# Chrome messing with email/password account settings webpage

Tags: forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, change-password, html-input

An account settings page has an email and password field so you can edit those. However, only in the Chrome browser, if you told Chrome to remember your username/password when you logged in, the account settings page acts funny. I've reduced the issue to just this webpage:

```
<form>      
  <input type="email" name="test" value="me@example.com"/>
  <input type="password" name="test2" value="mypass"/>
</form>
```

What happens is, the 2 fields are highlighted in yellow. If you change the email field in any way, the password field gets erased! Doesn't matter what they're named. It's basically the next password type field after any text input field with the stored password. How do I stop the password field from being erased?

A workaround I made is adding another password type field in between and adding `style="display:none"`. But that's ugly, is there a proper way to deal with Chrome in this way?

Comment: Looks like [Form AutoFill](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142893) fiddling around with your fields...

Comment: @alexander yes, I meant that to be obvious. Is there a good way to deal with this?

Comment: I meant to say that looks like a bug with the AutoFill :) Well, actually your UI flow is somewhat flawed... You should not use `value="me@example.com"`; try using `placeholder="..."` instead, and also try setting `autocomplete="off"` on both inputs (just a wild guess.)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov why shouldn't I use `value="me@example.com"`?

Comment: This may interfere with exactly the autocompleters and form fillers implemented by various browsers (they might think the user entered the value, should they inadvertently click the "Login" button or hit Enter).